# How replace Unicode Decimal Code character with a special caracter or without accent c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to replace unicode decimal code character to character normal o special

for example `&#201;` to É

with this i could solve`(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("PRUEBA05 JIM&#201;NEZ")`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please update your post to include what you have tried and what isn't working along with a minimal reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: &#201; to  É I don't know if exist any regex for replace o another method

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A3XDep does this work for you?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=net-6.0) which you could use like `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#201;")`

Comment: with this System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode i coud solve, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to replace accented characters such as `ö` or `é` with their unaccented ASCII equivalents, or decompose ligatures such as `æ`into its constituent letters (`ae`).

To do that, you need to play with Unicode normalization forms to decompose things, strip out the bits you don't want, and put it all back together.

You can read up on Unicode normalization forms at

- [Unicode® Standard Annex #15: Unicode Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)
  And about C#/.Net's support at
- [String.Normalize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=net-6.0)

Here are a couple of extension methods I wrote some time back to do exactly what it sounds like you want to do.

Note that this was written to handle the sort of text that our application encounters. If you need to go further afield in Unicode than Western European texts, you'll probably need to make some changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Common.Utilities.Private;

namespace Common.Utilities
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {

        public static string ToKebabCase( this string s, bool allowAccentedCharacters = false )
        {
            string transformed = null;

            if ( s != null )
            {
                transformed = Skewer(s);

                if (!allowAccentedCharacters)
                {
                    transformed = RemoveDiacritics(transformed);
                }

                transformed = transformed.ToLower();

            }

            return transformed;
        }

        public static string RemoveDiacritics( string s )
        {
            // NOTE THAT if we encounter data that uses stuff like ligatures (e.g, 'Æthelred the archæologist'), we'll probably
            // want to switch from NormalizationForm.FormD (canonical decomposition) to
            // NormalizationForm.FormKD (compatibility decomposition).
            //
            // Using FormD, the string 'Æthelred the archæologist' will remain unchanged;
            // using FormKD, it will be transformed into 'Aethelred the archaeologist'

            // decompose the string into  it's constituent octets.
            string canonicalDecomposition = s.Normalize( NormalizationForm.FormD ) ;

            // strip out any diacritical marks
            char[] buf = canonicalDecomposition
                .Where( c => char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark )
                .TransliterateSpecials() // kill off the really oddball ones
                .ToArray();

            // put it back together using canonical compostion 
            string transformed = new string(buf).Normalize( NormalizationForm.FormC );
            return transformed;
        }



    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private Ling extensions so we don't add this to every string and other IEnumerable of char that's out there.
    /// </summary>
    namespace Private
    {
        public static class Extensions
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Transliterat certain special character (see mapping below) to their common basic ASCII equivalents.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="chars"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>

            public static IEnumerable<char> TransliterateSpecials( this IEnumerable<char> chars )
            {

                foreach ( char ch in chars ?? Enumerable.Empty<char>() )
                {
                    IEnumerable<char> replacement;
                    bool hit = specialAccentedChars.TryGetValue( ch , out replacement );

                    if ( !hit )
                    {
                        yield return ch;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach ( char r in replacement )
                        {
                            yield return r;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Derived from analysis of the Unicode Character Database v12.1.0.
            /// 
            /// These are the "accented" letters in the blocks 'Latin-1 Supplement' and 'Latin Extended-A'
            /// that have no further decomposition defined even though there are common transliterations
            /// and substitutions for these letters (which see the table below).
            /// 
            /// Why 'Latin-1 Supplement' and 'Latin Extended-A', you might ask? These blocks:
            ///
            /// * Basic Latin (ASCII)
            /// * Latin-1 Supplement
            /// * Latin Extended-A
            /// 
            /// Cover pretty much any text we're likely to see, that is most Western European scripts.
            /// Once you get into Latin Extended-B, -C, etc., you're off into Non-European, African, and
            /// other oddball scripts (special letter for Egyptologists? Really?).
            /// 
            /// Basic Latin (ASCII) covers code point 0x0000 - 0x007F and doesn't have any special letters to worry about.
            /// 
            /// Latin-1 Supplement covers the remainder of the 8-bit range (0x0080-00FF: most common accented characters), and
            /// Latin Extended-A brings in most letters found in Eastern European languages (Latvian, Lithuanian, Croatian, etc.)
            /// 
            /// Might note that we are extremely unlikely to ever encounter some of these letters:
            /// 
            /// * The letter 'Kra', for instance, "is a glyph formerly used to write the Kalaallisut language of Greenland and is
            ///    now only found in Nunatsiavummiutut, a distinct Inuktitut dialect.
            ///    
            /// * And the letter 'Eng'? It represents the sound 'nngg' as in "singing". It's used by the Washo language, spoken by the Washoe,
            ///   a [small] Native American tribe on the California/Nevada border.
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            private static readonly Dictionary<char,IEnumerable<char>> specialAccentedChars = new Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<char>>
            {
                { '\u00C6' , "AE" } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE
                { '\u00D0' , "TH" } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH
                { '\u00D8' , "O"  } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE
                { '\u00DE' , "TH" } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER THORN
                { '\u00DF' , "ss" } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S
                { '\u00E6' , "ae" } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER AE
                { '\u00F0' , "th" } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH
                { '\u00F8' , "o"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE
                { '\u00FE' , "th" } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN
                { '\u0110' , "D"  } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE
                { '\u0111' , "d"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE
                { '\u0126' , "H"  } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H WITH STROKE
                { '\u0127' , "h"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER H WITH STROKE
                { '\u0131' , "i"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I
                { '\u0138' , "q"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER KRA
                { '\u0141' , "L"  } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH STROKE
                { '\u0142' , "L"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE
                { '\u014A' , "N"  } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ENG
                { '\u014B' , "n"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER ENG
                { '\u0152' , "OE" } , // LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE
                { '\u0153' , "oe" } , // LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE
                { '\u0166' , "T"  } , // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH STROKE
                { '\u0167' , "t"  } , // LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH STROKE
            };

        }

    }
}
```